# Case insensitive commands in Vim

Tags: vim

I am looking for a method to allow me passing commands to vim in insensitive case. (I am not looking for case-insensitive search or file/directory name completion)

For example, i want to be able to save a file by pressing either `:w` or `:W`. Is that possible?

Comment: do you want to do it for all built-in commands? or only `:w`

Comment: Surely, all commands.

Comment: There's no general solution (expect very hacky ones that will probably interfere with some sort of arguments, or miss out on some commands); you'd have to do this for _each_ command; see linked question. Better learn to type more precisely; with Vim, that's a worthwhile investment!

Comment: @Kent; what if i like to make specific commands. like `:w`, `:q` ?

Comment: @MuhammadReda then you can either create mapping, or customized command. Mapping is sufficient for this case.

Comment: Any docs or reference for how to do mapping?

Comment: @MuhammadReda `:h cnoremap` try `cnoremap Q q`

Comment: @Kent: No, with that simple one, you cannot search for `Quick` any more (except with `<C-V>` first). Better use one of the solutions in the linked question.